# How do you add legend to an X,Y plot

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I want to add a legend to this X Y Graphic. I can add a legend but it's simply wrong. I want the legend to show the different 'Region Names'

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df_HP.groupby('Region_Name').plot(x='Date', 
y='First_Time_Buyer_Average_Price', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can use plt.legend(['Date','FIrst_time_Buyer_Average_Price'])

Comment: Well, I want the legend to show each 'Region_Name'. But when I do try it gives me all the different Region names, but the X Y values for 'Date and 'First_Buyer....' Do not match the colours shown in the legend box